# Include & tags don't work in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am confused about Ansible-Playbook that don't work if i'm using include & tags in `main.yml` (tasks).

Command:
`ansible-playbook -i digitalocean/inventory.ini ans-graylog.yml --tags "insglog"`

```
PLAY [Setup Graylog] **************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************
ok: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

PLAY RECAP ************************************
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx            : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

If I remove `--tags "inslog"`, it will be successful. All tasks will be run normally.

`main.yml (Tasks)`

```
---
- include: gray.yml tags=insglog
- include: fbeat.yml tags=insfbeat
```

When I used `--tags="inslog"` in `ansible-playbook` command, `gray.yml` was not executed.

I have tried `include_task`, `import`, `import_task`. But, I got the same result.

Could you please help me to correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tags` is not a parameter of a module, but a parameter of a task.

You should specify `tags` at task level:

```
---
- include: gray.yml
  tags: insglog
- include: fbeat.yml
  tags: insfbeat
```

---

**Explanation**

Your example uses Ansible notation (with equal sign) which transcribes to YAML as:

```
- include: gray.yml
    tags: insglog
- include: fbeat.yml
    tags: insfbeat
```

And this is incorrect; `tags` declaration will be ignored.